# How can i read a local txt file using javascript and winJs?

Tags: javascript, file, winjs

Hi I would like to read a txt file using javascript.
I saw a lot of ways to do it but still not clear for me. my file will be read for a simple path like "c:/javascript/file.txt.

my file is like this

New York

California

Miami

i would like to get every element (by line) and put it into a var.

Any help will be appreciate, thank's

Comment: as far as i know it's impossible.only if you are using ActiveX

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript - read local text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file)

Comment: I saw this 2 solutions, they do not work for me